# Does EAAccessoryManager list bluetooth headsets connected?

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

As per the title, will the iOS call EAAccessoryManager.connectedAccessories return connected bluetooth headsets (including those that are not made-for-iphone registered?
Dont need to connect but want to know if I can use the proximity of a device to trigger an event.

Answer (score 2):

No.  It will only return EAAccessory instances representing Made for iPod devices that publish a protocol.  From the External Accessory Programming Topics:

> Communicating with an external
>   accessory requires you to work closely
>   with the accessory manufacturer to
>   understand the services provided by
>   that accessory. Manufacturers must
>   build explicit support into their
>   accessory hardware for communicating
>   with iOS. As part of this support, an
>   accessory must support at least one
>   command protocol, which is a custom
>   scheme for sending data back and forth
>   between the accessory and an attached
>   application.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I too had read this statement but was unsure whether this meant they would not be returned or just return nil when accessed through EASessons – initWithAccessory:forProtocol: method.